# How to take a string and use it as an identifier to call a function?

Tags: python, string, function, identifier

I have created an autograder for my classes that uses a command line argument to call the associated function for that problem set. I need to extract the command line argument as a string, and then use it as a function call. In the example I'm assigning the string to pset and then calling pset and passing studentFile as the argument. The problem is that the interpreter sees it as a string and not an identifier.

[this is a picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbEQx.png)

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    try:
        # find and store the file
        studentFile = helpers.findInSubdirectory(sys.argv[1])
        for i in studentFile.split('/'):
            if i.endswith('.py'):
                pset = i[:-3]
        pset(studentFile)
```

Comment: You can get your function from globals()[pset](studentFile)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: This kind of thing is usually done with a dictionary in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unsafe way to do this would be to use `eval` or look at the `globals()` dictionary. A slightly safer way would be to create a string-to-function mapping in a dictionary, and look up the function from the mapping.

```
def foo():
    print('hi')

def bar():
    print('see you')

funs = { 'foo': foo, 'bar': bar }
funs['foo']()
```

Comment: Using a dictionary works but it still requires me to make another structure to contain the function calls. I was hoping there was a simpler way to just convert a string into an identifier. Thank you.